# Convert from VB.NET to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net-to-c#

In C# you can not have indexed properties. That said, how do I convert the following code from VB.net to C#?

```
Private _PatchSpectrum(49) As Double

Public ReadOnly  Property GetPatchSpectrum() As Double()
    Get
        Return _PatchSpectrum
    End Get
End Property

Public WriteOnly Default Property PatchSpectrum(idx As Integer) As Double
    Set(ByVal value as Double)
        _PatchSpectrum(idx) = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: "as in C# you can not pass parameters" To the set, yes you can.  It just defaults to the name value with the type that's returned.

Comment: I'll point that returning the array is generally not the best of ideas, and the `GetPatchSpectrum` property is not a very well named (sounds a lot like a method).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd do this like:

```
private double[] _PatchSpectrum = new double[49]

public double[] GetPatchSpectrum
{
    get { return _PatchSpectrum; }
}

public double this[int index]
{
    set { this._PatchSpectrum[index] = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or with methods instead of properties:

```
double[] _patchSpectrum = new double[49];

public void SetPatchSpectrum(int index, double value) 
{
    _patchSpectrum[index] = value;
}

public double[] GetPatchSpectrum() 
{
    return _patchSpectrum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) on your object, which is how collection classes like `List` work.  E.g:

```
public double this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            // This indexer is very simple, and just returns or sets
            // the corresponding element from the internal array.
            return _PatchSpectrum[i];
        }
        set
        {
            _PatchSpectrum[i] = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wanted to return the entire array

Comment: Ah yeah, this is just the indexer bit.  As noted above, there's no trick in returning an array, you just create a property to return it.  If you don't want the `get{}` method  you can elide it.

Comment: dsolimano, thanks this is first I am answering this post but looks like I can not mark multiple post answers. alteast it was helpful. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

For future code conversions check out the [Telerik Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/).

Comment: Unfortunately, the code converter doesn't handle this case correctly.

Comment: I used Telerik for rest of the code but it failed for this as C# does not accept property with parameters.