# VB to C#: "Extension Property" with Getter / Setter

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm working on a VB to C# conversion and I came across, in VB, an "Extension Property" (I'm not sure how to call it) that I would like to replicate in C#.

```
    Public Class PeopleCollection
    Inherits Dictionary(Of System.String, People)
    
    Property IfExist(ByVal name As String) As Double
        Get
            If Me.ContainsKey(name) Then
                Return Me(name).Age
            End If
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            If Me.ContainsKey(name) Then
                Me(name).Age = value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
    
End Class

Public Class People
    Property Age() As Integer
    Property Name() As String
End Class
```

The nice thing about it is that it is called as an extension method but can be used as a get or set using the same name. It does reduce code on the caller side.
I find it very interesting and wish I could figure out a way in C#.
So far the only solution I found was to create 2x separates methods: GetIfExists, SetIfExists, which makes it slightly less convenient and force me to update every references throughout the rest of the code.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert from VB.NET to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426733/convert-from-vb-net-to-c-sharp)

Comment: It's more commonly called a "parameterized property" in VB, and your solution of using separate 'get/set' methods is the only solution I'm aware of.

Comment: You could create an overloaded extension method, e.g., `public static void IfExists(this Dictionary<string, People> source, string name, int value)` and the `public static int IfExists(this Dictionary<string, People> source, string name)` counterpart. After that, you have , e.g., `var people = new PeopleCollection(); int age = people.IfExists("someName");
people.IfExists("someName", 30);`  -- Of course `PeopleCollection` doesn't need a Property anymore.

Comment: Yes !! Thank you Jimi ! I was playing around with extension methods and wasn't able to make it work because was creating the same signature (dummy) The "setter method" doesn't need a value being passed to it... I think this is it. I wish I could have used it as a property because now I need to update the 1000+ "Dict.IfExist("James") = 25" with "Dict.IfExist("James", 25) "

Comment: @Jimi, could you please post your answer and I will vote it as the solution. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, C# does not support parameterized properties.  To consume VB (or other .NET language) parameterized properties in C#, you must call the get and set routines.  The other option aside from what Jimi mentioned that might be used is to return a helper object with an indexer.  (Even more unfortunately, the expression machinery doesn't work right for them either...)

Comment: If you like this solution, post the answer yourself. I consider this a specific use-case work-around. I wouldn't do this, I'd use an Interface (`<in TIndex, TValue>`) to generate an indexed Class object that wraps a Dictionary. Of course there's more code to change, but you have to consider that C#, though similar, is not VB.Net, you have other tools available (i.e., I suggested this for your convenience, in this context, but I don't like it).

Answer (score -2):

I recall using this tool when I had a similar project: https://converter.telerik.com/

It generated this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class PeopleCollection : Dictionary<System.String, People>
{
    public double IfExist
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.ContainsKey(name))
                return this[name].Age;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.ContainsKey(name))
                this[name].Age = value;
        }
    }
}

public class People
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where is `name` coming from?

Comment: "Where is name coming from?" --> That's the issue, it doesn't exists. If you copy the converter output in Visual Studio, it'll show you that it is not good code. I think the issue is that, in C#, property cannot take arguments (very newb to C# so I'm probably wrong or using wrong terms). Other online converters will always split it into two methods.

Comment: @Sirosimo I think your terminology is fine.